# How can I set html and body padding to 0 in Vuejs without affecting bootstrap elements?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, padding

I'm creating a bootstrap navbar in my Vuejs project and it's spaced with some left and right margin without adding any body or html padding to 0.

When I go to welcome.blade.php file and set body and html padding to 0 like so:

```
*{
   padding: 0!important;
 }
```

Then I get no right and left space on my bootstrap navbar but algo I get no space between elements inside my bootstrap navbar.

I want to set HTML and body padding to 0 without affecting bootstrap element paddings/margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use * that means all tags and classes,

You have to use

```
 body {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
 }
```

Comment: Still getting the left and right spaces unless I set padding and margin as u did inside *{}

Comment: Do you have anything inside your component? I guess you wrap it with something else. Can you change your browser? Chrome, opera, mozilla etc? Sometimes browser overrides it.

Comment: No, I don't have any style inside my Vuejs component.

Comment: I solved it, i had to specifically set padding:0 to my <app> component.